# Reset function that will reset fields to what they were based on which of two functions was last run

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple browser game to practice JS where you kill a bad guy. There are 2 modes, easy and hard. I am trying to set up a reset button that will reset information fields depending on which of the modes the game is in.

example
playing easy, click reset and the game resets by running easyMode function
playing hard, click reset and the game resets by running hardMode function

apologies if this is simple, this is why I'm making practice games

I've tried to make the function that currently has a specific class selected run when running reset function

```
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#new");
var easy = document.querySelector("#easy");
var hard = document.querySelector("#hard");
var playerHealth = document.querySelector("#php");
var playerFocus = document.querySelector("#pfocus");
var bossHealth = document.querySelector("#bhp");
var attack = document.querySelector("#attack");
var strong = document.querySelector("#strong");
var regenerate = document.querySelector("#regen");
var modeButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".mode");
var defenseLog = document.querySelector("#defenselog");
var offenseLog = document.querySelector("#offensivelog")
var boss = {}
var player = {}


setupModeButtons();
easyMode();
reset();

function hardMode(){
    player.health = 12;
    player.focus = 15;
    boss.health = 25;
    update()
};

function easyMode(){
    player.health = 10;
    player.focus = 10;
    boss.health = 12;
    update();
}

function update (){
    playerFocus.textContent = player.focus;
    playerHealth.textContent = player.health;
    bossHealth.textContent = boss.health;
};

function setupModeButtons(){
    for(var i = 0; i < modeButtons.length; i++) {
        modeButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            modeButtons[0].classList.remove("selected");
            modeButtons[1].classList.remove("selected");
            this.classList.add("selected"); 
        });
    }
}

function reset (){
    if(easyMode.classList=="selected"){
        easyMode();
    } else if(hardMode.classList=="selected") {
        hardMode();
    }
}
```

The reset button works but always resets with function easyMode no matter which has had the class "selected" applied with function setupModeButtons

Comment: You need `==` or `===` to compare. `=` is assignment. `easyMode.classList=="selected"` for the top one, `hardMode.classList=="selected"` for the bottom check. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: You are definitely right about my comparison operator. I changed that but the issue still stands and I still need help figuring out what I should use instead.

Comment: **updated function**  function reset (){
 if(easy.classList=="selected"){
  easyMode();
 } else if(hard.classList=="selected") {
  hardMode();
 }
}

Comment: Does the `easyMode` element have any other classes?

Comment: If it does you'd want to use [`classList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check if it has the class.

Comment: Yes, both the easy and hard buttons have the class "mode" assisgned to them which is necessary for referencing with variable modeButtons.

Comment: awesome, I'm going to try that right now **edit - Yaakov Ainspan comment to use .contains() has fixed it** is there anyway to mark this as solved? I'm still pretty new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.classList` is a DomTokenList (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), so it never be `"selected"`. Use the `contains` method instead:

```
function reset (){
    if(easyMode.classList.contains("selected")){
        easyMode();
    } else if(hardMode.classList.contains("selected")) {
        hardMode();
    }
}
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: someone pointed me in this direction in the comments above. this is what I went with and it now works perfectly. `function reset (){
 if(easy.classList.contains("selected")){
  easyMode();
 } else if(hard.classList.contains("selected")) {
  hardMode();
 }
}`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a DOM tree that containing something like this

```
<button class='mode'>Easy</button>
<button class='mode'>Hard</button>
```

The code might be more readable if you explicitly named the buttons, rather than using an implicit array `modeButtons[i]` for your difficulty scale.

```
<button class='mode mode-easy'>Easy</button>
<button class='mode mode-hard'>Hard</button>
```

Your `reset()` function is trying to reference the prototype object chain of the functions `easyMode.__proto__.classList` and `hardMode.__proto__.classList` rather than the state of the DOM button. Also note that .classList is an array and not a string, so needs .contains()

```
function reset(){
    if( modeButtons[0].classList.contains("selected") ) {
        easyMode();
    } else if( modeButtons[1].classList.contains("selected") ) {
        hardMode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Another comment solved my issue but you are definitely right about the naming of buttons, that will also bring more consistency in my JS. That's much more similar to how the setupModebuttons function is written. I'm still pretty new to this so working on consistency and readability. Thank you!